# iOS: What is the default background color of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, default, background-color

I want to set background color for labels inside tableViewCell to opaque but I need default background color of uiTableViewCell that Apple provides.

So how can I get this background or what color is it?

Regards

Comment: What color do they have when you do not change the background color? This should be the default.

Comment: How about using those labels's superView property and fetching the backgroundColor from that point?

Comment: This also does not work. I get black background. This is probably cos cell's backgroundColor is null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution: [Different cell bg color depending on iOS version (4.0 to 5.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733828/different-cell-bg-color-depending-on-ios-version-4-0-to-5-0)

To sum up I just implement method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To reset the color of a recycled (dequeued) [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html), this has worked for me in iOS 5, 6, and 7:

```
cell.backgroundColor = nil;
```

As others suggested here, I logged the value of that property for a newly created cell. I saw `null`. That gave me the idea to nil out the property. Seems to be working in all 3 iOS versions.

As I vaguely recall, iOS has changed drastically the way defaults are set for colors in [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and UITableViewCell. In some versions parent containers colors were picked up. In some versions, that default color was greyish white, but changed over time. In iOS 7 White is applied regardless of parents. Note: Don't quote me on this paragraph; look it up if you care. The point is that answers telling you to set a specific color are giving you bad advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can log the background color of the cell

```
NSLog(@"cell background color is %@", cell.backgroundColor);
```

or the cell's contentView

```
NSLog(@"cell contentView's background color is %@", cell.contentView.backgroundColor);
```

You could also just set your label's color directly:

```
label.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor;
```

Comment: Neither is working!? I get this: "cell background color is (null)" and "cell contentView's background color is (null)". I logged this in cellForRowAtIndexPath method on device and simulator. This is strange. Why is that?

Comment: U, did I mention that I have custom cells "cell = [[TableViewCellController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];". Is this a problem ?

Comment: TableViewCellController? Is a subclass of what?

Comment: It's a subclass of UITableViewCell like it should be... I get null for backgroundColor in both uiTableView class and its uiTableViewCell sublcass. It's really strange. Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UIColor *color = [cell backgroundColor];
    NSLog(@"%@",color);
```

Result is

> 2011-11-08 17:09:20.101 test1[5439:207] UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1

It indicates that default color is Red=1, Green=1, Blue=1, alpha=1. It's a white color.

Note, that UITableViewCell also has `contentView` property, which contains real visible color.