# What is the default background color of a UITableViewStyleGrouped styled UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to set the backgound color of a cell in my UITableView. That works fine. Then, later, I want to restore it to the original color. Now, under iOS4 that color is white, under iOS 5 that color is #f7f7f7 (See
 [Different cell bg color depending on iOS version (4.0 to 5.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733828/different-cell-bg-color-depending-on-ios-version-4-0-to-5-0) )

Now, I can always ask the cell in viewDidLoad what's its background color is, but that seems like a hack. I'd love it if there was a call already in place by Apple. Since it is iOS version dependent, it won't be a static UIColor method.

So, is there a cleaner way of getting this color or do I just have to ask when the dialog first comes up?

Interesting, I can't get the background color programatically! If I do this:

```
backgroundCellColor = usernameCell.backgroundColor; 
NSLog(@"*** backgroundcolor is: %@",backgroundCellColor);
```

then when I look at my Console I see this:

```
2011-12-06 15:11:08.686 Ferret[47035:f803] *** backgroundcolor is: (null)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try to set the cell back to this value of `(null)`. Just to be certain, cache the variable and feed it back that value.
What does it do?

Comment: It gets the vertically striped border, not the F7 gray.

Comment: If I set it to a hardcode F7 gray it looks perfect, but that's barely acceptable.

Comment: like you said, barely... I've never played with that. I hope some one will come up with a good answer I'm curious.

Answer (score 1):

I think asking for the original is NOT a hack. For one thing, it allows Apple to change the look as they see fit. It also allows YOU to customize things in a nib file.

Comment: Well... If I was setting a custom color in the nib file then I agree with you. But what I want is Apple's default. And I set it to Apple's default in the nib file.

Comment: David answered before I edit my question, so I can't even ask anymore, since I just get a null back. So I'm still looking for an answer...

Comment: So the most likely cause of that is that usernameCell is nil at the time you're inspecting it. Where is this being called?

Comment: Is it nil? Is usernameCell an outlet? HOw does it get instantiated?

Comment: Yes, it is nil. It is an IBOutlet, with a property and a synthesize. I just moved my query to textFieldDidEndEditing, figuring it has to be setup by then, nope, still nil...

Comment: Pretty sure once you can figure out why it is nil, everything will start working. You're not actually using the property here, though I doubt that matters. Doublecheck that the outlet is hooked up correctly?

Comment: Yeah, it is hooked up because I can change the color to red or blue or whatever.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense, if it's hooked up it's not nil. (I'll admit my cells are created from their own nib, not a joint nib which yours seems to be. But they definitely have a non-nil backgroundColor.) So where are you successfully setting color? Same place you can't read it?

Comment: I set the color in textFieldDidEndEditing and didSelectRowAtIndexPath. But I'm setting it via setBackgroundColor, and getting it via inCell.backgroundColor and inCell.contentView.backgroundColor, both of those are nil when I call it in viewDidLoad